# Cancel oldest raw in DB after calling findAll() method

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a table for users password recovery requests. These are his columns:

- ID
- idUser
- createdDate
- expiryDate
- token
- isExpired

If a User tries to make multiple requests I want to find all the rows  with his ID, and if they are > 1, set them to `isExpired = true`.
Doing so, I want to consider as valid only the last request.

How can I achieve this?

This is how I'm doing it now, assuming that in the table there is only one row with his ID:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $newPassword = $form->get('password')->getData();

    $currentToken = $request->query->get('token'); 

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $passwRecovery = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\PasswordRecovery')->findOneBy(array('token' => $currentToken));

    if (empty($passwRecovery)) {

        return new Response ("<h3>Access denied!</h3>");
    }

    else {

    if (new \DateTime('now') > $passwRecovery->getExpireDate())
    {

        return new Response ("<h3>Token expired!</h3>");
    }

    $idUser = $passwRecovery->getIdUser();

    $userRecoverPassw = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $idUser));

    $userRecoverPassw->setPassword($newPassword);

    $em->persist($userRecoverPassw);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response ("<h3>Password reset ok!</h3>"); }
```

Consider I have 3 rows with the same idUser, if I use:

```
    $passwRecovery = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\PasswordRecovery')
    ->findAll(array('token' => $currentToken));
```

I will get 3 results. How can I set the `isExpired = true` only for the first two?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just set isExpired true each time you add a new PasswordRecovery row?  It also seems strange that you would use the same token for each row.

Comment: I don't want to use the same token more than one time. The token is unique and generated for every single request. I created the IsExpired column to take track of all the user password recoveries, but at the same time I want that only the last request a user made is valid.

Comment: If token is unique then how could the findAll at the end of your question return more than one record?  And if each time you add a new recovery record you expire any previous records for that user then it seems like your requirements would be met.

Comment: The findAll() method at the end of my question will search for all the equal `idUser`. This is the process: the user receives an email with a token attached. He clicks the link, then the program search for that token in the db to verify if it's valid. If the token is in the db, then the program will get the `idUser` of that user, and search for other active requests. If there are some requests, the program will delete them.

Comment: I've added a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that at the end worked for me, hope this can help. If there are any better ways to do what I'm posting here, I'm open to suggestions.

```
public function resetPasswordAction(Request $request) {

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()

    ->add('password', 'password')

    ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Send'])

    ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $newPassword = $form->get('password')->getData();

    $currentToken = $request->query->get('token'); 

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $passwRecoveryObject = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\PasswordRecovery')->findOneBy(array('token' => $currentToken));

    if (empty($passwRecoveryObject)) {   

        return new Response ("Impossible to execute the request!");
    }

    else {

    if (new \DateTime('now') > $passwRecoveryObject->getExpireDate()) 
    {

        return new Response ("Token expired!");
    }

    $idUser = $passwRecoveryObject->getIdUser()->getId(); 


    $userRecoverPassw = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\PasswordRecovery')->findBy(array('idUser' => $idUser)); 

    $end = end($userRecoverPassw);  //$end is the last record of the password_recovery table
    $count = count($userRecoverPassw); //count of the rows in password_recovery with the id of the current User


    foreach ($userRecoverPassw as $element) { //here i'm setting to 1 the isExpired column for all the rows with the same id, except for the last one

        if (--$count <= 0) {
        break; }

        $element->setIsExpired(1);
        $em->persist($element);
        $em->flush(); 

    }

    $userResetPassw = $em->getRepository('\UserBundle\Entity\User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $end->getIdUser()->getId()));  //User that need to reset the password

    if ($end->getIsExpired()==0) {

    $userResetPassw->setPassword($newPassword);
    $end->setIsExpired(1);

    $em->persist($userResetPassw);
    $em->flush(); 

    $em->persist($end);
    $em->flush(); 

    return new Response ("Password succesfully updated!");
    }

    else { return new Response ("Expired link!");}

} }



    return $this->render('UserBundle:AccountUser:reset_password.html.php', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),));


}
```